# Django access related items in template

Tags: django, orm

Please help me I’m stuck in understanding how Django ORM works.

Here is my very simple models:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I want a template that looks like: 
Department 1

- Employee 1
- Employee 2

Department 2

- Employee 3
- Employee 4

But I can’t figure out what I should do in my view and(or) template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview):

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class DepartmentListView(ListView):
    model = Department
```

Create a template within your apps directory.
Within your template you have access to `{{ object_list }}` which is a list (QuerySet) of your Department objects.
So you could use:

```
{% for department in object_list %}
    {{ department.title }}

    {% for employee in department.employee_set.all %}
        {{ employee.first_name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You probably should start by going through the [official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/), it will greatly explain everything you neet to get startet.

Comment: Could you show me the full traceback?

Comment: Thank you man you litterally save me, it was my mistake